# What is the last permission/user and can I delete it?

Tags: security, permissions, windows-11

I have installed Windows 11 Pro from USB Memory Stick I created with Rufus.
I installed the Windows on my Samsung NVME Drive.

The Permissions of Drive C are as appear in the screenshot.

My question is: What is the last permission/user to who it belong to and can I delete it ?

[Drive C-Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWWfw.jpg)

Comment: It belongs to the system. **DO NOT DELETE IT** I search for the GUID in your screenshot and got multiple responses and results all saying it’s a background user account created by Windows which is absolutely harmless. I’ll let somebody with more time answer this question in greater detail